# What's the part of speech of 'She Them'?

Tags: pronouns, ellipsis

> She had used her fitness and fighting skills to survive many times. She didn’t always kill with a gun from long range. Sometimes her targets were right in front of her, trying to murder her as fiercely as **she them**.

I am curious into finding out what part of grammar is *she them*. I am fairly sure that it is correct grammar but then again I'm still a rookie at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an example of [ellipsis](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ellipsis), a technique employed to avoid repetition. Without [ellipsis](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis) being employed in your example, it would read like this:

> Sometimes her targets were right in front of her, trying to murder her as fiercely as she (**was trying to murder**) them.

The author has used ellipsis to express the reciprocal action of both parties trying to murder each other.